# Get Date by passing dayofweek, weekofmonth, monthofyear and year using c#

Tags: c#

I need a method which can return a date after taking 4 inputs, dayofweek, weekofmonth, monthofyear and year. I have tried the following but it fails when 4th week of month doesn't have all days, so I return 28 to be at safer side. I would like to have a complete solution and better than this if possible. Please ignore my parameters, I know I can improve it by passing a date instead. Here is my code;

```
public static DateTime GetDateByDayOfWeekOfMonthOfYear(int dayOfWeek, int weekOfMonth, int monthOfYear, int year)
        {
            var firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(year, monthOfYear, 1);
            var firstDay = (int)firstDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek;
            var addor = 0;
            if (firstDay == (int)DayOfWeek.Monday)
                addor = 0;
            if (firstDay == (int)DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
                addor = 6;
            if (firstDay == (int)DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
                addor = 5;
            if (firstDay == (int)DayOfWeek.Thursday)
                addor = 4;
            if (firstDay == (int)DayOfWeek.Friday)
                addor = 3;
            if (firstDay == (int)DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                addor = 2;
            if (firstDay == (int)DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                addor = 1;
            var resultantDate = firstDayOfMonth.AddDays((7 * weekOfMonth + addor) - (7 - dayOfWeek) - 1);

             return resultantDate.Month == monthOfYear
            ? resultantDate
            : firstDayOfMonth.AddDays(27);
        }
```

Comment: You can use `DateTime.DaysInMonth(Int32, Int32)` to check how many days there are in given month in given year.

Comment: How do you define weekofmonth?

Comment: @qxg weekofmonth can be any number from 1 to 4.

Comment: Which day is the first day of week? Monday or Sunday? Do you consider 2015-11-30 the 5th week? Which date in the first week of Dec. 2015, 12/01 or 12/08?

Comment: ...@Learner...some months like january 2016 have six weeks....

Comment: @qxg sorry, I misunderstood your question, I consider Monday as first day of week and I don't need to consider 5th week of the month. For example 07/12/2015 is the first day of first week of 12th month of the year 2015.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way - for the weekday of your choice, and for the first or a later occurrence of this weekday:

```
// Select year, month, weekday, and occurrence of weekday.
int year = 2015;
int month = 10;
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday;
int occurrence = 1;  // Valid values: 1 to 5.

// Constants.
const int daysInWeek = 7;
const int maximumWeek = 5;
const int minimumWeek = 1;

occurrence = occurrence < minimumWeek ? minimumWeek : occurrence;
occurrence = occurrence > maximumWeek ? maximumWeek : occurrence;

DateTime first = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
int primoOffset = (dayOfWeek - first.DayOfWeek  + daysInWeek) % daysInWeek;
DateTime dayInMonth = first.AddDays(primoOffset + daysInWeek * --occurrence);
if (dayInMonth.Month != month)
{
    // Week 5 belongs to the next month.
    // Return value for the last occurrence.
    dayInMonth = dayInMonth.AddDays(-daysInWeek);
}

return dayInMonth;
```